# Does it matter what I name my open source license file?

Tags: github, open-source, licensing

I have been starting to try to upload some of my stuff to [**GitHub**](http://www.github.com/), and I have read a few articles lately with some hard data showing that [**most of the repositories on GitHub aren't licensed properly**](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/04/18/github_licensing_study/). I would like this not to be the case. I decided to start including the [**MIT license**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) with most of my projects from now on and I got to wondering whether I should name it `LICENSE.txt`, or perhaps `LICENSE.md` (I like this one) would be better? Then I began to wonder about the more general question: Does it matter what you name the file that holds your open source license *at all*? For example is your project really licensed properly if you have a valid license inside but the file is named `VOIDLICENSE.md`? I know that is a bit contrived, but it demonstrates what I am trying to ask. Are there any limits on what I name the file I place my license in, or for that matter where that file is placed? If it is buried deep down in the directory structure somewhere does it still count? If there is anything else in the file does it still count? I imagine if the license is changed from the template at all it would not be considered a valid MIT license, but if something else is in the file would that void it?

Comment: It's best to follow conventions here so people can easily find out if they can reuse the code or not.   If I encountered an OSS license I_AM_GOING_TO_SUE_YOU_IF_YOU_USE_THIS.txt I would catch the irony but be concerned about ironic lawsuits as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter that much, as long as you choose something sensible.

Since you're using an open source license, you probably want to make it easy for a fellow developer to discover that he may in fact use your code under the MIT License. This is done by making your license file easily discoverable.

Anything like LICENSE, LICENSE.MD, LICENSE.TXT in the root of a repository can be considered easily discoverable. I think you may also assume that if a human does not find a LICENSE file, he would look for something else - say COPYING too.
You want to prevent conflicting claims about licensing. Don't say in your README that something is licensed under BSD, while saying in a separate license file that it's MIT.

You may also want to consider discoverability by non-human agents. npm looks for a "license" field in the package.json, and displays this on the package info page at npmjs.org.

The CommonJS spec actually speaks of a "licenses" field. I know for a fact that "license" is also supported by npm though, since I'm using it myself. I also know that npm accepts a simple string value for the license field. i.e. `"license":"MIT"` works.

> licenses - array of licenses under which the package is provided. This property is not legally binding and does not necessarily mean your package is licensed under the terms you define in this property. Each license is a hash with a "type" property specifying the type of license and a url property linking to the actual text. If the license is one of the official open source licenses the official license name or its abbreviation may be explicated with the "type" property. If an abbreviation is provided (in parentheses), the abbreviation must be used.

http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1

Also, it's good to know that in principle, you retain copyright over anything you publish. If no license is specified, or a (potential) user cannot find a license, he must assume he has NO license to use your work, other than any fair-use provisions under a country's copyright laws. See for discussion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/pick-a-license-any-license.html

> if the license is changed from the template at all it would not be considered a valid MIT license, but if something else is in the file would that void it?

It would indeed be confusing to at the same time claim you are making something available under the MIT license, while the actual license text says something (slightly) different. However, you are absolutely entitled to license your work any way your want (within the limits of the law. Some requirements can't be made - and are void).

I think the biggest risk (if anything) of slight ambiguity in licensing is that a (potential) user might claim he was under the impression that he was entitled to use your work under the terms of the MIT License, because your license header said so. You'd have more difficulty suing this person in court for any wrongdoing if he did not adhere to any additional terms. He could claim innocence, as it were.

I'd say: Don't use the name of an established License (MIT, BSD, GPL, etc) unless you want to license under exactly these terms. Or if you do use such name, always say "MIT+MY_REQUIREMENTS" or so. "MIT" just wouldn't be a right "summary".

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time for such a detailed answer! Do you have any thoughts on the grey area in using code that is available publicly in a place like GitHub, but without a license. I know that technically legally the author retains copyright, but could you, as you say, probably claim innocence, due to the fact the code is hosted publicly in a place like GitHub?

Comment: First of all, it may not be that productive to discuss a matter of guilt or innocence. I think it's better to look at what would happen in practice. If you'd discover someone using code that you have published somewhere without a license, and you don't want this code to be used by this person, I think you could demand him to stop using it. I think you'd also stand a fair chance of enforcing this demand in court, if the person refuses to do so. (continued)

Comment: At the same time, if you want to pursue retroactive damages from this person, he might respond that we was using your code in good faith. As in "why else would you post it on github like that?". If his plea for acting in good faith is accepted probably depends much of the specifics of a project. I think that if it's small and trivial it's more likely; large and unique - less likely.

Comment: However, I don't think that something like this has ever been tested in court. Typically, people who publish any meaningful code with the intend to license it strictly do this quite purposively and as such will take the time to add a proper license file (GPL or so). People who casually publish code while aiming for the broadest use will not be the ones wanting to stop someone from using the software, or to pursue damages. Most companies nowadays are so accustomed to using open source (MIT and such, at least) that they won't have problems with acknowledging your work when you ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can Change the title of the licence without worries, but there is requirements concerning location. you must :

- provide the full text of the licence in the root directory of your source project (usually in a file called LICENSE.TXT)
- provide the full text of the licence in the root directory of your non-source project distributions (usually in a file called LICENSE.TXT).

Check out that link for more details : http://www.oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/opensourceyourcode#applying-the-licence

Comment: In the GNU land (and somewhere else too) the file is usually named COPYING

Comment: yes, as long as you display it at the right place, changing name doesn't invalidate the license.